# counting instances that happens in certain hours in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My situation is like this.

I got this spreadsheet that is getting a lot of inputs of hours when something happened (the vertical table on the right in the picture- every time something happened it saves the time) in the 2 lines of the "factory"

Also, the hour that the "factory" was opened is entered in cell O4 (this case 05:30)
when i enter the opening hour the table below changes itself automatically from the open hour i entered.

Now, my problem is that I got this horizontal table (divided it to 2 tables 1 below the other so it can fit in screen better). In this table I want to show how many instances in each hour.
The rule is for example everything between 14:30 to 15:30 is going for the cell 15:30 and so on.

The formula in each cell on the horizontal table is:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A30,">"&N7,A2:A30,"<="&M7)
```

That example is from cell M8- every cell just checks how many in the range are between the hour before and the hour now. (cells N7 and M7)

The PROBLEM is only in midnight, in this configuration for example every instance that will be between 23:30 to 00:30 will be ignored by excel, i need to fix it, now every time the cell that contains midnight is empty.

How do I fix it?? I really need help on that.

(wanted to post a picture but it wont let me cuz im new :-(  )

Comment: I just edited your question, removed an embarrassing typo that might put people off and made your question more readable. Please keep in mind that you communicate with written text. Making that text easy to understand is in your own interest, so, please run a spell check and use proper case and punctuation. With regards to posting a picture, there are free file sharing sites out there and you can always post the text of a link.

Answer (score 0):

Since only interested in times, and only displaying times, add `1` to the relevant data (ie all those starting `00:`).

An easy way to do so is to enter `1` in a cell somewhere, copy that , select all the data to be adjusted and Paste Special, Operation, Add, OK.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that (as far as i understand it) by additioning two countifs with a simple "+" like this:

```
=countifs(range1;criteria1a;range1;criteria1b)+countifs(range2;criteria2a;range2;criteria2b)
```

where

range1 is the previous column and criteria1a/b is 23:30 < x < 24:00

range2 is the current column and criteria2a/b is 00:00 < x < 00:30

or something similar

PS: and happy new year to eastern Europe (UTC+3) !